# Linker error: /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lgcc_s

Tags: 12.04, gcc

I am trying to compile `symlinks` ([tar.gz-file](http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/s/symlinks/symlinks_1.2.orig.tar.gz)), which is a very small tool with one line for compilation:

```
gcc -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes  -O2 -N -s -o symlinks symlinks.c
```

which gives the error

```
....    
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lgcc_s
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lgcc_s
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

The output of

```
/sbin/ldconfig -p | grep libgcc
```

is

```
libgcc_s.so.1 (libc6) => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
```

and trying to include the mentioned directory directly

```
gcc -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -L /lib/i386-linux-gnu/  -O2 -N -s -o symlinks symlinks.c
```

produces the same error.

Three questions:

1. Why does it not work with the first command, as the lib seems to be in the search path
2. Why does including the path itself does not help
3. How to fix this?

Comment: Since you are passing the `-static-libgcc` flag, shouldn't you be looking for `libgcc_s.a` rather than `libgcc_s.so`?

Comment: Sorry, the original command (from Makefile) is as above, *without* `--static-libgcc`.

Answer (score -1):

Solution: Omitting the option `-N`.

Comment: Please explain why this will solve the problem.

Comment: This is a low quality answer. Please [edit] to explain how this will work.